# Cannot get desired value out array within the hash in php

Tags: php

I'm trying to get the data within the "local_images".

```
$config = [
    'gallery_name' => 'Rezin Gallery',
    'unsplash_categories' => ['Painting', 'Pattern Wallpapers', 'Painted', 'Texture'],
    'local_images' => ['images\1.jpg', 'images\2.jpg', 'images\3.jpg', 'images\4.jpg'],
];
```

I thought this would work:

```
foreach ($config as $local) {
    echo "<p>{$local['local_images']}</p>";
}
```

But I keep getting this error message:  Uncaught TypeError: Cannot access offset of type string on string.
Eventually I'd like to use the source from the config hash to echo out img tags on the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps this:

```
<?php
$config = [
'gallery_name' => 'Rezin Gallery',
'unsplash_categories' => ['Painting', 'Pattern Wallpapers', 'Painted', 'Texture'],
'local_images' => ['images\1.jpg', 'images\2.jpg', 'images\3.jpg', 'images\4.jpg'],
];
foreach($config['local_images'] as $img) {
    echo "<p>{$img}</p>";
}
```

Comment: Wow I forgot that I could do that! This solved my issue thank you!!!